# c# Mock interface vs mock class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm new to the moq framework in .net.
From my research online, it seems like there are 2 ways to make use of this framework. Either mock the interface or mock a concrete class. Seems like when mocking concrete class, only `virtual` method can be mocked. In my case, I just want to mock a couple method of a class which implements an interface.

For example, if we have the following:

```
public interface Ifoo
{
    int Bar();
}

public class Foo : Ifoo
{
    public virtual int Bar()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public Client(Ifoo foo)
    {
        var temp = foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Now if I need to unit test Client, I need to pass a mocked Ifoo object in the ctor. In this case, should I do:

```
var mock = new Mock<Ifoo>();
```

or

```
var mock = new Mock<Foo>();
```

Does it make a difference in my case? What's the pros and cons of mocking interface vs mocking class? To me, mocking interface is always a better solution since mocking a class can only give the mock of the `virtual` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some points to consider:

- Your client consumes IFoo, so that's what you should mock.
- If your client consumes a concrete class, you should think about refactoring your client to consume the interface or abstract class instead to comply with SOLID principles.
- If your client consumes a mock of Foo during your test instead of the interface and it relies on some of the non-mocked behavior in that test, you're not really writing a unit test since you're testing the behavior of more than one unit.
- If your client doesn't consume any non-mocked behavior during the test then you might as well just pass a mock of the interface anyway.

tldr: Classes should consume interfaces or abstract classes rather than concrete classes. Tests should mock interfaces or abstract classes rather than concrete classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So can I say mocking a concrete class's virtual method is a fallback solution,only if that concrete class doesn't implement any interface/abstract class?

Comment: Yes, I would only mock a concrete class as a fallback. However, writing test cases reenforcing an existing violation of SOLID only increases your technical debt which is why I would consider refactoring the consumer to rely on interfaces or abstract classes and update the concrete class to implement/extend those first before I'd write the test case with a mocked concrete class. Ideally your consumers will depend on contracts of behavior input and output and not specific implementations of that behavior itself. Doing that increases maintainability and makes testing simpler as well.

Comment: Of course, you could say the same thing about abstract classes as well since they can implement behavior -- might as well just make them implement an interface and standardize all service consumptions to interfaces.