# Unit testing Delete Method of API producing -> Can not instantiate proxy of class

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a Unit test case for the delete method of the below controller

```
public class AssetProxyController : Controller
    {
       
        private IRiskAssetProxyService _assetProxyService;       
       
        public AssetProxyController( IRiskAssetProxyService assetProxyService)
        {
            _assetProxyService = assetProxyService;
        }

        [HttpDelete("{assetId}")]
        public ActionResult Delete(string assetId)
        {
            if (_assetProxyService.DeleteAssetProxyMapping(assetId))
            {
                return Ok("AssetProxy Deleted");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Unable to delete AssetProxy");
            }
        }
  }
```

***Test***

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void Delete_ShouldReturnDeleteAssetProxy()
    {
        //Mock
       var mockContext = new Mock<MainDBContext>();
       var faker = AutoFaker.Create();
       var assetProxyMappings = faker.Generate<List<AssetProxyMapping>>();
       var mockAssetProxyDbSet = GetQueryableMockDbSet<AssetProxyMapping>(assetProxyMappings);  
       mockContext.Setup(c => c.AssetProxyMapping).Returns(mockAssetProxyDbSet);
       //Test
       var mocklogger = new Mock<ILogger<RiskDataControllerDbAccess>>();
       var positiondbaccess = new Mock<RiskAssetProxyDbAccess>(mockContext,mocklogger);
       var mockserviceLogger = new Mock<ILogger<RiskAssetProxyService>>();

        var positionService = new Mock<RiskAssetProxyService>(positiondbaccess, mockserviceLogger);
       var positionController = new AssetProxyController(positionService.Object);
          
        Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
    }
```

But i keep getting the exception

```
Test method Risk.DataService.UnitTests.API.AssetProxyControllerTests.Delete_ShouldReturnDeleteAssetProxy threw exception: 
    Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException: Can not instantiate proxy of class: Risk.DataServices.RiskAssetProxyService.
    Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
    Moq.Mock`1[Risk.DataServices.RiskAssetProxyDbAccess]
    Moq.Mock`1[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Risk.DataServices.RiskAssetProxyService]]
```

Comment: `var positiondbaccess = new Mock<RiskAssetProxyDbAccess>(mockContext,mocklogger);`

you are not mocking an interface here. mocking concrete classes has restrictions, and is also not recommended as not being very S-O-L-I-Dish.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282374/c-sharp-mock-interface-vs-mock-class

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer Changed that, this produces a new error `Test method Risk.DataService.UnitTests.API.AssetProxyControllerTests.Delete_ShouldReturnDeleteAssetProxy threw exception: 
    System.ArgumentException: Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks.`

Comment: well, i think the problem goes a bit deeper, because now that you you did change it so that no concrete types are mocked, you must remove the constructor argument from moq - if thats not possible (you have structured dependencies, instead of flat dependencies), you could try to get more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414704/mocking-objects-with-moq-when-constructor-has-parameters

Answer (score 1):

The currently shown test is completely over-engineered based on the shown subject under test.

Given the shown `Delete` controller action, the test case should be simplified

```
[TestMethod]
public void AssetProxy_Delete_Should_Return_Ok() {
    //Arrange
    string assetId = "assetId";
    var serviceMock = new Mock<IRiskAssetProxyService>();
    serviceMock.Setup(_ => _.DeleteAssetProxyMapping(assetId))
        .Returns(true);
    
    AssetProxyController controller = new AssetProxyController(serviceMock.Object);
    
    //Act
    ActionResult result = controller.Delete(assetId);
    
    //Assert - using fluent assertions
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
    string expected = "AssetProxy Deleted";
    OkObjectResult okResult = result as OkObjectResult;
    okResult.Should().NotBeNull();
    string actual = okResult.Value as string;
    actual.Should().Be(expected); //same as Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Another test case can be done to assert bad requests and would be similar to the case shown above except that the mocked service will be arranged to return `false` in order to cause the expected behavior and the assertion updated accordingly

Comment: Thanks.I'm just new to unit testing.How can I verify that a record is actually deleted ? Shall I create a context of the production db , start a transaction -> delete records -> verify-> roll back.As per this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-with-the-database